# Filtering array where property contains string

Tags: javascript, json, linq.js

I'm trying to filter some JSON data to search for job roles that starts with a certain string.

The JSON looks like :

```
"periods": [
        {
            "periodName": "Week1",
            "teamName": "Tango",
            "roleName": "SoftwareEngineerII",
            "roleExperience": "2",
            "id": "cc1f6e14-40f6-4a79-8c66-5f3e773e0929"
        },
        ...
    ]
```

I want to filter for roleName that starts with "Software" so that I can see a list of all Software Engineer levels, and it filters out other roles.

I'm not sure how to do a "starts with" or "contains" here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jsk5awbb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to filter the array where one of the string properties contains a value... How else would you check if a string contains another string?

You could use a regex:

```
var str = 'SoftwareEngineerII';
if (str.match(/^software/i)) {
    // it starts with 'software'
}
```

So you need to convert this to a predicate that could be used in your filter.

```
var query = Enumerable.From(data.periods)
    .Where("!!$.roleName.match(/^software/i)")
    .ToArray();
```